# Multi target synthetic data generator

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, normal-distribution, cross-validation, gaussian-process

I need to create multi-objective synthetic dataset to test optimization models

Ideal would be: 100 features that are correlated with 10 targets, and the goal of the model is to predict the targets from the features and predict what features might achieve the desired target mix, the ideal format would be:

feature1,feature2,feature3...feature100,target1,target2...target10
90,1.2,5,89,110,10...11,120

I can generate random but the goal is to check how quick the models find correlations and find optimals

Comment: This is more like a description of a project, so what is your question exactly?

Comment: My question is how to do it